# What version of visualvm works with Java 6?

Tags: java, macos, osx-mavericks, visualvm

I'm using Mac 10.9.1 and Java 1.6.45 .  It is not an option for me to upgrade my Java version at this time.  I want to use visualvm to analyze heap dumps, but the latest version on http://visualvm.java.net/download.html only works with Java 7 and above.  What version of VisualVM will work with Java 6 and where can I find this mystical version?

Comment: You should be able to type in `jvisualvm` into a Terminal session to access a built-in version that functions the same as the separate download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VisualVM 1.3.6 works with JDK 6. You can download it from this page: http://visualvm.java.net/releases.html. You can also install JDK 7 next to JDK 6 and use VisualVM 1.3.7.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) Oracle site it should be a command-line tool built in to your JDK distribution. From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html), it was first bundled in Java 6u7, so you should definitely have it.